# Found fs.open with non literal argument at index 0 when using url built from arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to do something like this (typescript)

```
window.open(`https://somelink/certificate/${regNumber}?registrationNumber=${type}`);
```

where `regNumber` and `type` are very dynamic.
ESLint is giving me an error
**Found fs.open with non literal argument at index 0  security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename**

I know this is https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal path traversal vulnerability, but simply cannot figure out how to go around it. Any ideas? Thanks

Screenshot:[image]

Comment: What is the `windows` variable? (that's not `fs.readFile`)

Comment: Just a way to open a new tab in chrome https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open. btw this is working fine, but for security reasons should be fixed. Still reports fs.open error.

Comment: `window` is well-known, but `windows` sounds like something entirely different - is that just a typo?

Comment: I have fixed it, it was typo lol

Comment: Seems as if that es plugin just checks for keywords, and not if `open` actually belongs to `fs` ([False positive detect-non-literal-fs-filename on _.exists #26](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/issues/26)), so you can get that warning at various places in the code that are not in any way related to `fs`.

Comment: Updating eslint-plugin-security to 1.6.0 fixes this problem: https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-security/issues/26#issuecomment-1379905095

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, this rule can be safely ignored.

What the rule does is, it makes a list of [these object keys](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/blob/main/rules/data/fsFunctionData.json), which includes `open`, and then checks whether any property accessed in the code (or, more specifically, any MemberExpression) matches one of those keys.

So, while it'll generate a warning for `fs.writeFile`, and `fs.open`, for example, it'll also generate one for `window.open` - *despite the fact that the client-side `window` object is completely different from `fs`*.

`fs` methods allow for broad manipulation of the server's filesystem. Allowing arbitrary access to this is a bad idea.

`window.open` only allows a client's browser to open a window to another address, which is nearly innocuous and has very little chance of harming anything.

There's still a potential small vulnerability, but the potential vulnerability will exist regardless of your `window.open` code - if the webserver is set up improperly and allows arbitrary URL accesses to do something improper (which would be pretty unlikely), that means there's a big issue to fix on the server - but it's not an issue that client-side code should try to deal with.

If the project you're working on does not contain any server-side code, feel free to disable the `security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename` rule for the whole project.